# Do Mongodb's "greater" and "less" operate faster when there is an index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.RESULT.find({
    MDD: {
        $gt: -3
    }
})
```

This is my MongoDB Query.

I found out that it is really slow to have a condition such as "$gt" or less than, as there is a lot of data.

Can it make "$gt" operation faster to index a field (MDD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are. According to [Mongo Index Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/). If your query is based on one field `MDD` then you should make an index for a single field, else - make a compound index. To check the difference you could use [`explain`](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/shell-methods/collection/db-collection-explain.php) syntax for your query before and after field indexing.

Comment: Thank you, I hope this Question can be helpful for people who couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a good idea to put your index on it. You can put also multiple indexes on multiple fields. If you have an embedded array for example you can also put an index on it too if you need to search in it.

Be aware of too much indexses it could slow down your inserts. If you have too many indexes it will slow down your inserts because mongo needs to rebuild all your indexes. This could be a cause of the excessive write lock.